# What kind of journal 'The Journal of Neuroscience Methods' is?

Tags: publication

I am looking for some journal that publishes neuroscience research with focus on computational and/or methodological aspects. The [*Journal of Neuroscience Methods*](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-neuroscience-methods/) appears on a Google search but it has relatively low impact factor among the journals I have checked this far. What kind of reputation the journal has? Are there other good alternatives?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is opinion based and may be better off at Academia.SE as discussions on impact factor etc. shouldn't be held here.

Comment: I think that discussing publication options related to where to publish in the cognitive sciences is, or should be, on topic for this site. That said, I imagine the question could be refined: asking "What kind of journal is ..." is a little tricky to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but more based on surface observations.

- At time of posting, Journal of Neuroscience Methods has an impact factor of 2.0. This is quite a respectable impact factor.
- The scimagojr puts in the second quartile of "neuroscience (miscellaneous)" journals http://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=16765&tip=sid&clean=0
- It is published by Elsevier. While Elsevier has its detractors, particularly around its open access policy, it is a respectable academic publisher.